# include php file containing function in a web page

Tags: php

I have a php file which contains php function. I have to receive its return value in a part of my web page. Where do I put the `include`? in the `head` or in the `body?` how can I call the function inside my web page?

Comment: Can you show the php and html code?

Comment: Do you mean the included file will execute the function and you want to use the result of this execution elsewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include the php file wherever you want, as long as it is before you call the method contained in it. You call the function between `<?php ?>` tags. You can use `echo` to output it to the page.

So if you have `myfunc.php` that looks like this:

```
<?php
    function myfunc() {
        return 'asdf';
    }
?>
```

Then in php that includes it you can do:

```
<?php
    include('myfunc.php');
    echo myfunc();
?>
```

You can also choose to put the `include` method anywhere above that makes sense. The very top of the file is a common choice.

Also note that if your php file contains functions, you should probably be using `require_once` instead of `include`. See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php

Comment: +1 for 'anywhere before the function call'. +1 for 'common choice'. +1 for 'require_once'. Oops - can +1 only once. ^^

Comment: @Martin i can help you with that ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can't call php code from a html file. However, you could simply make your html web page into a php web page like this:

```
<?php
    include("yourphpfunction.php");
?>
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
....
<!-- put php result here: -->
<?php echo myfunction(); ?>
... more html
</body>
</html>
```

and save it as .php instead of .html.

That's all the magic.

You can also wrap it all up in one statement:

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
....
<!-- put php result here: -->
<?php
    include("yourphpfunction.php");
    echo myfunction();
?>
... more html
</body>
</html>
```

as long as your file gets parsed as php.

Answer (score 0):

you can put the include in the top of your html page like

```
<?php
   include 'file.php';
?>
<html>
   <head>
     .....
```

and on your HTML, you can do something like:

```
<div>my stactic text <?php echo myFunction(); ?></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should require (require_once) the file, before you reach the part where your returned output should be echoed.

required file.php:

```
<?php $test = "hello world"; return $test; ?>
```

include include.php:

```
<?php $output = require_once('file.php'); echo $ouput; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a php webpage, you can't call a php function or include a php page in html file.

Assuming your webapge is php, You can include that file in the top of the page inside the  tag. But be sure to include the file before the function is called.

```
require_once 'path/to/your/file';
or
include_once 'path/to/your/file';
```

Then you can call the function in your php file like:/

```
$test = functionInYourIncludedFile();

echo $test;
```

Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

look below :

```
<?php 
  function doSomthing() {
     return $var
  }
?>
<html>
<?php echo doSomthing() ?>
</html>
```

or

```
<?php include('functionFile.php') ?>
<html>
<?php echo doSomthing() ?>
</html>
```